# LINQ retrieving a record based on date

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to learn a bit about ling. in the code below, I'm trying to retrieve records that have an activeuntil date which after the current date.

```
        Dim context As DynamicsCRMEntities = New DynamicsCRMEntities()
    Dim CustomerNoticeQuery = From NewsArticles In context.BusinessUnitNewsArticles Where NewsArticles.NewsArticle Like "customer" Select NewsArticles.ArticleTitle, NewsArticles.NewsArticle, NewsArticles.ActiveUntil

    For Each result In CustomerNoticeQuery
        If Date.Now.Date >= result.ActiveUntil Then
            CustomerNotice.Text = result.NewsArticle.ToString
        End If
    Next
```

I keep running into this error but cannot get my head around it

System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean LikeString(System.String, System.String, Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompareMethod)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: My first question, are you absolutely sure that all values for ArtiveUntil in CustomerNoticeQuery are of type date?  Are there perhaps null values in there tripping you up?

Answer (score 0):

The `Like` operator you are using there is VB-specific and, as the error message says, is not supported by EF. You need to use standard .NET functionality that the LINQ to Entities provider understands. If you want to do a partial match on `Strings`, that means using `String.Contains`:

```vb
Dim CustomerNoticeQuery = From NewsArticles In context.BusinessUnitNewsArticles
                          Where NewsArticles.NewsArticle.Contains("customer")
                          Select NewsArticles.ArticleTitle, NewsArticles.NewsArticle, NewsArticles.ActiveUntil
```

You really ought to break your LINQ queries over multiple lines like that too, for the sake of readability.

Note that that addresses your actual issue, which has nothing to do with dates, so the date part to the question was completely irrelevant. That said, why would you do a query with a `Where` clause and then use a loop to filter the results of that query? Why would you not include the additional filter in the `Where` clause? I'd also consider using a better subject variable name in the query:

```vb
Dim today = Date.Today

Dim CustomerNoticeQuery = From article In context.BusinessUnitNewsArticles
                          Where article.NewsArticle.Contains("customer")
                          And article.ActiveUntil < today
                          Select article.ArticleTitle, article.NewsArticle, article.ActiveUntil
```